# How to send markdown or HTML message via Viber bot

Tags: bots, viber, viber-api, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

Is it possible to send formatted message from Viber Bot with Markdown or HTML tags?

If yes - then how? What attributes to specify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response from **Viber Developer Support**:

> formatting text with our API is only possible for keyboard or rich media buttons, **not for text messages**.

Answer (score 1):

Good news from future, add a character on both sides without space:
bold with *,
italic with _,
wasted with ~,
monospace with ```.
But the formatted view is rendered only in the mobile version.